# JQuery to update textbox depending on DDL selection

Tags: c#, jquery, post, model-view-controller, get

I have a serial number generation method on MVC 4

When i select a Product ID from the DDL and press create it, it generates a serial number no problem to the Index page

However i would like to have the Serial number presented to the user during the creation process, so as soon as they select a value from the DDL, the serial number will be generated and displayed in a read only box.

Below is my snippet that does the serial generator

```
//
    // POST: /Item/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Item item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string SerialNumber = string.Format("SN/{0}/{1}", DateTime.Now.Year, item.ProductID);
            item.SerialNumber = SerialNumber;

            db.Items.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ProductID = new SelectList(db.Products, "ProductID", "ProductID", item.ProductID);
        return View(item);
    }
```

I have very little experience with jquery so it would be great to get pointers or help on how to accomplish this idea. If there is even a better way than jquery please let me know :)

Any info requests i will be happy to supply

Thanks

Comment: this will give you can exact idea http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b58fde6b-415e-454d-985b-d5dc4ad2fca8.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give you can exact idea binaryintellect.net/articles/… –  @Frebin Francis (credit goes to Frebin)